# What am I missing with CSS default Tab text color not readable on page refresh

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tabs

I have some CSS that I am working on and when the page loads my default tab text stays black and becomes unreadable.  Once I click around the text reveals itself to be white.

I would like the default / first tab to be white text when the page refreshes.  Please help.

This it the url: https://wholesale.greenenvee.com/45374-2/

This is the CSS I wrote so far:

```
.tab-format [role="tab"][aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
     border-top: 6px;
  border-top-color: lightgray;
  color: white;
}

.tab-format a:focus {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}


.tab-format a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS for the active LI `.ui-state-active` and then target the anchor:

```css
.ui-state-active .ui-tabs-anchor {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Or for short:

```css
.ui-state-active a {
    color: #fff;
}
```